# Find common id field between two seperate array object and merge it angular js

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have two separate data array objects with multiple fields:
[image]
[image]
This is how the **data** object array looks like with the `eventId` field in it too.

[image]

The **annotateData** object has `eventId` field that is also present in the **data** object. I want to check which data element has the same `eventId` present in the **annotateData** and then merge that **annotateData** element to the **data** object element. So the output will have data object with annotateObject fields added to it.

```
data: [{
  0:{ annotateData fields + already present data fields} //if eventId matches
}]
```

Is there a more efficient way to do so rather than running the loop through the entire data object?

Comment: Please share the input arrays and expected output.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32701359/combine-two-arrays-of-objects-using-underscore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that there is another efficient way of doing this rather than looping. Although I would implement a few helper methods to iterate over and merge (as given [here](https://github.com/sagrawal31/angular-extras/blob/v0.2.1/src/extras/array.js)):

```
Array.prototype.indexOfWithKeyValue = function(key, value) {
  var index = -1;
  var _this = this;

  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    var item = _this[i];
    if (item[key] === value) {
      index = i;
      break;
    }
  }

  return index;
};

Array.prototype.find = function(key, value) {
  var index = this.indexOfWithKeyValue(key, value);
  return this[index];
};
```

And then iterate over:

```
var annotateData = [];  // sample data
var data = [];  // sample data

angular.forEach(annotateData, function(aData) {
    var matchingData = data.find("eventId", aData.eventId);

    if (matchingData) {
        // Matching fields from "annotateData" will be merged over "data"
        angular.merge(matchingData, aData);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the helper functions. I will use this method to solve my problem.